# Selenium DOM selection on common lisp

Tags: selenium, common-lisp

I am working with https://github.com/TatriX/cl-selenium-webdriver 
cl-selenium at the moment. I have been reading the source code back to front few times but I am having difficulty finding any function to chain select elements such as `(find-element element)`. I am able to find elements without traversing, but not being able to traverse is quite inconvenient.

Is there any way to traverse the DOM? or how would you extract the whole html to be parsed with plump or lquery?

Comment: You could ask on an issue I think.

Comment: @ehvince The package does not seem to be well maintained it has 0 issue posts on github

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Sure, but it is decently active with a few contributors, so you could add dynamism over there (and sometimes it brings movement indeed). It will also be easier for next users to find out your issue, and for developers to be aware of it. Anyway, glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Finally found one solution, 
`(execute-script "return document.documentElement.innerHTML" '())`